# Remove everything after @ til next space until no more matches are found?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string looking like this: `Hello @StackOverflow! How are you today? I'd like to !sh @StackExchange`

I would like it to look like this: `Hello ! How are you today? I'd like to !sh`
I would like to remove `@` and anything after it, until the string is cleared of all matches.

The solution I came up with only removes the first occurence.

```
re.sub('@\S+ ', '', myString)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `re.sub`:

```
@\w+\s*
```

**Code:**

```
>>> s = "Hello @StackOverflow! How are you today? I'd like to !sh @StackExchange"
>>> print ( re.sub(r'@\w+\s*', '', s) )
Hello ! How are you today? I'd like to !sh
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `@`: Match literal `@`:
- `\w+\s*`: Match 1+ word characters followed by 0 or more whitespaces

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you! Just a question, will this work even if a third @StackExchange were added? :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the trailing space in your string.

```
import re
myString = "Hello @StackOverflow! How are you today? I'd like to !sh @StackExchange"
re.sub('@\S+', '', myString)
```